# How do I iterate over a vector of string vectors? (c++)

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, vector, iterator

I need to loop over ***vector of vector of strings*** in the same manner as I would do this on this example with *integers*:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> stuff;
    //fill the inner vector, then insert it into the outer vector

    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
    {
        vector<int>temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(i);
            ++i;
        }
        stuff.push_back(temp);
    }

    //display all elements ...
    for (int i = 0; i < stuff.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stuff[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << stuff[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

But strings require different approach as they are more complex,
Here I`m iterating over 1-Dimensional string:

```
vector<string> first_arr = {};
string line;
ifstream myfile("source.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        first_arr.push_back(line);  //READ from file
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

But I have completely stuck on going into the inner circle.
Also, I am expecting strings of very different length

I was not using c++ for a while so, please forgive my question if it seems too obvious to you,

Comment: Would you believe that the code you have for iterating over a two dimensional vector of `int`s will work, mostly unchanged, with a vector of strings? It should at least compile, as is, with only the variable names changed. Although it's not a particularly efficient way to iterate, in C++, it'll work.

Comment: The only thing your sample loop is doing with the inner element type is printing them -- the usage of `string` is no more complex than the usage of `int` in that regard. Although note that your second code block is only a vector of strings, not a vector of vectors of strings.

Comment: _Here I'm iterating over 1-Dimensional string vector_ ...you are not iterating over the vector `first_arr`. You are iterating over the rows of `myfile` and add these lines to the vector `first_arr`.

Comment: Incidentally, breaking a problem into smaller parts. If you have trouble doing something with a vector of vectors of things, then write a function that does something with each element of a vector of things, and write another function that that calls that function of a vector of things.

Comment: I guess I am not far from it, but something is still missing. I`ve spent few nights over this and finally, decided to ask for help; (Logically, String != int, it`s more complex; you can not run through string, as it ints)

Comment: @Hurkyl, that is the case, I have broken down the problem in smaller parts; I can iterate over 2Dim vector of integers, but I stuck on going into inner loop while iterating over strings, So I would appreciate if someone clarifies this for me;

Comment: Did you try my suggestion, iterating exactly how you would iterate over a two-dimensional vector of `int`s. Don't be afraid to try it. You'll be surprised when it works. This is not a practical joke.

Comment: @Maxim classes are about abstractions and providing interface for data. if you had some trivial structure or self-designed class, that's other case, you have to implement proper interface for that (  that is, methods, constructor, operators for serialization). You're using string class that is part of C++ and stream classes that are part of C++, _logically_ they were designed  to work together. And why you need two-dimensional vector of strings? you can have stringstream, or single-dimensional vector that represents content of file. You should read documentation : http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with three `vector`s of `string`s of sizes `5`, `10`, and `15`. This examples uses `C++11`'s [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to print the `vector`s.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using SList = std::vector< std::string >;
    using VList = std::vector< SList >;

    VList vlist;

    for ( int i = 5; i <= 15; i += 5 )
    {
        SList slist { i };
        std::fill( slist.begin(), slist.end(), "Test" );
        vlist.push_back( slist );
    }

    for ( const auto& v : vlist )
    {
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for ( const auto& s : v )
        {
            std::cout << s << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ Test Test Test Test Test }
{ Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
{ Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
```

Here's the live example on Ideone: http://ideone.com/PyYD5p

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same logic.
Unless you want to print every string one letter at a time.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<std::string> > vec;

    std::string tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        vector<std::string> v;
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            std::cin >> tmp;
            v.push_back(tmp);
        }
        vec.push_back(v);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << vec[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to do the c++11 way, you could replace the last loop for this snippet:

```
for(const auto &subVec : vec)
{
    for(const auto &str : subVec)
    {
        std::cout << str << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```